# unable to display value from a dropdown list on another php page using session

Tags: php, session

I have an issue that I cannot display the selected value using session. Can I check that previously I have a created a dropdown list(Page1.php) and display my selected value on Page2.php using session then on page2.php I have another droplist list as below (page2.php) but I could not display the selected value on page3.php using session. I cant figure where it is wrong.

**Page2.php:**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<select name="amtoftable" size="1" class="StyleTextField" id="amtoftable" >
<p>
</p>
<?php if($_SESSION['svenue'] == 'Bliss'){ ?>
<option value="-1"> Select no.of tables</option>
<?php $dbtables = $_COOKIE["amtoftable"];
 if ($dbtables == "41")
 echo "option selected = 'true' value = '41'>41</option?>";
 else echo "<option value='41'>41</option>"; ?>


<?php $dbtables = $_COOKIE["amtoftable"];
 if ($dbtables == "42")
 echo "option selected = 'true' value = '42'>42</option?>";
 else echo "<option value='42'>42</option>"; ?>

  <?php
     if(isset($_POST['SubmitBooking'])){
      if($_POST['amtoftable'] == '41')
          $stable = '41';
      }
         else if($_POST['amtoftable'] == '42')  
         $stable = '42';
      }
            //save session
           $_SESSION["ctables"] = $_POST['amtoftable'];
          die("<script>location.href = 'Payment.php'</script>");
     }
```

**page3.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<label for="label-tables">No.of tables:  </label>`enter code here`

<?php echo  $_SESSION['amtoftable'];?>
```

Comment: hi i missed out this part                                                                                  <?php
         if(isset($_POST['SubmitBooking'])){
    if($_POST['amtoftable'] == '41')
        $stable = '41';
    }
             else if($_POST['amtoftable'] == '42') 
       $stable = '42';
    }
                //save session
               $_SESSION["ctables"] = $_POST['amtoftable'];
              die("<script>location.href = 'Payment.php'</script>");
   }

Answer (score 1):

One page2 you say `$dbtables = $_COOKIE["amtoftable"];`, but on page3 you are calling `$_SESSION['amtoftable']`. Also, where is `$dbtables` assigned?

Answer (score 0):

an option will be selected when you put this condition

```
  <option value="41"  <? if($value=='41') {echo "selected=selected" }?> </option
```

other wise it will not select the value in select option once check with this and let us know where your strucking behind will help

Comment: "<option value='41'>41<? echo "selected=selected" ?> </option>                                do you mean by the above?